Meld not opening on Ubuntu 22.04
I've installed Meld on Ubuntu 22.04 with apt but when I try to open it with /usr/bin/meld I get this:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/meld", line 79, in <module>
    import meld.conf  # noqa: E402
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'meld'

I've read that it can be due to python versions. In /usr/bin I have
python              python3             python3.10          python3.10-config   
python3-config      python3-futurize    python3-pasteurize 

The default python version is 3.9.8: how can I solve this?

The default python version in 22.04 is 3.10.
You must have changed the default python version at some point.
This is may have severe consequences, and it may stop APT from working, or stop the GUI from loading.
Please revert back to the default python version and meld should work. How to revert depends on how you installed the new python version. If you used apt, then use
sudo update-alternatives --config python3

If you used any other non-standard method, then refer to the manual you followed to install that.
If you want a different python version, please use a virtual environment, and don't touch the default python version.

how to revert it?

@FrancescoBoi Depends on how you installed new python. How did you install it?
